# nginx reverse-proxy returns 400 bad request when serving web-app from a container in a Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

In my setup there's two containers working in the same pod: django app with some static files, and nginx container serving those files. When I'm using docker-compose with both containers on my machine- everything works fine, but when I'm trying to move the setup into a K8s cluster, nginx returns 400.

Here's my nginx.conf:

```
upstream myapp{
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /home/app/web/static/;
    }
}
```

deployment.yaml:

```
spec:

  replicas: 2

  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
    
      volumes:
        - name: static
          emptyDir: {}
          
      containers:
        - image: {name}/backend:django
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: myapp
          volumeMounts:
          - name: static
            mountPath: /home/app/web/static
          envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: myapp-secret
          - configMapRef:
              name: myapp-config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8000
              name: gunicorn
        - image: {name}/backend:nginx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: nginx
          volumeMounts:
          - name: static
            mountPath: /home/app/web/static
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
            
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred
```

NodePort Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
    - port: 8000
      targetPort: 80
```

Checking Service creation:

```
D:\yaml>kubectl get svc myapp
NAME    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
myapp   NodePort   {CLUSTER_IP}     <none>        8000:31443/TCP   8s
```

Checking IP for the cluster node:

```
D:\yaml>kubectl get node -o wide
NAME                   STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP   EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE                       KERNEL-VERSION    CONTAINER-RUNTIME
{NAME}                 Ready    <none>   14d   v1.20.2   {INTERNAL-IP} {EXTERNAL_IP}    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.0-11-amd64   containerd://1.4.3
```

And when I'm trying to access via `http://{EXTERNAL_IP}:31443/` I get these logs from my nginx container:

```
D:\yaml>kubectl logs my-app-75139f968c-452mf nginx
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist, exiting
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
{EXTERNAL_IP} - - [25/Feb/2021:02:26:25 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.41 YaBrowser/21.2.0.1097 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36" "-"
{EXTERNAL_IP} - - [25/Feb/2021:02:26:25 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 154 "http://{EXTERNAL_IP}:31443/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.41 YaBrowser/21.2.0.1097 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: In your nginx configuration, try: `proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;`

Comment: now it gives me `[error] 21#21: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` and if I change upstream to localhost too, then the container refuses to start at all

Comment: Is your django app listening on port 8000?

Comment: `[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
[2021-02-25 03:57:22 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16` 
thats logs from django app container

Comment: Since you deployed the two containers in a single pod, they share the same namespace. nginx should be able to access the django container using localhost.

Comment: I've also tried removing the upstream section of the nginx config and setting proxy_pass to `http://127.0.0.1:8000;`, and explicitly setting gunicorn to `127.0.0.1:8000` but that doesn't help either